# When executing the stored procedure from VBA getting error "Procedure or function expects parameter @empid which is not passed"

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I have written a stored procedure to insert the data into a table. When I execute that into SQL Server 2012 it works fine while in VBA throws error

> procedure or function expects parameter @empid which was not provided

I tried to resolve with different combinations of connection strings, `CommandType` etc but it does not resolve. While code seems perfectly fine, please assist me to resolve it.

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertDataIntoEmployee]
    @empid INT,
    @empname VARCHAR(20),
    @empage INT,
    @empsalary DECIMAL(8,2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[employee] (empid, empname, empage, empsalary)
    VALUES (@empid, @empname, @empage, @empsalary)
END
```

VBA code:

```vb
Private Sub Exec_StoredProcFromExcel_Click()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim res As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mobjCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strConn As String
Dim par1 As Object
Dim par2 As Object
Dim par3 As Object
Dim par4 As Object
'Dim empname As Varchar
'Dim empage As Integer
'Dim empsalary As Single
Dim indRecordSetFields As Integer

'Dim strQuery As String
'con.Close
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set res = New ADODB.Recordset
Set mobjCmd = New ADODB.Command

strConn = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
'strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
con.Open strConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set par1 = mobjCmd.CreateParameter("@empid", adInteger, adParamInput)
Set par2 = mobjCmd.CreateParameter("@empname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30)
Set par3 = mobjCmd.CreateParameter("@empage", adInteger, adParamInput)
Set par4 = mobjCmd.CreateParameter("@empsalary", adDouble, adParamInput)

With mobjCmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "Exec [dbo].[spInsertDataIntoEmployee]"
    .CommandType = 1 'adCmdStoredProc=4 does not work while adCmdText=1 and adCmdUnknown=8 both work for me
    .CommandTimeout = 45

    .Parameters.Append par1
    .Parameters("@empid").Value = 111
    .Parameters.Append par2
    .Parameters("@empname").Value = "majid rajih"
    .Parameters.Append par3
    .Parameters("@empage").Value = 34
    .Parameters.Append par4
    .Parameters("@empsalary").Value = 200000

    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empid", adInteger, adParamInput, 111)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "majid khan")
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empage", adInteger, adParamInput, 30)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empsalary", adSingle, adParamInput, 250000)

    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empid", adInteger, adParamInput, , ThisWorkbook.Sheets("employee").Range("A2").Value)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("employee").Range("B2").Value)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empage", adInteger, adParamInput, , ThisWorkbook.Sheets("employee").Range("C2").Value)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empsalary", adSingle, adParamInput, , ThisWorkbook.Sheets("employee").Range("D2").Value)
    ' repeat as many times as you have parameters

    .Execute
End With

'With res
'res.CursorType = adOpenStatic
'res.LockType = adLockOptimistic
'res.Open mobjCmd 'This executed the stored proc
'End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try executing the command after the with block. It sounds silly but I think I've come across this before.

Comment: Have you tried `CommandType=4` with `CommandText` being just `dbo.spInsertDataIntoEmployee`?

Comment: Also `.Execute` statement should be `Set res = .Execute` and the recordset shouldn't be `Set` before that.

Answer (score 4):

You are running the command in the text mode.
Your full query is `Exec [dbo].[spInsertDataIntoEmployee]` which does not include any parameters.

`CommandType` should be `adCmdStoredProc`, and `CommandText` should be the procedure name, without `exec`.

```vb
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "[dbo].[spInsertDataIntoEmployee]"
```

If you want to keep `adCmdText`, list all parameters in the query:

```vb
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = "exec [dbo].[spInsertDataIntoEmployee] @empid, @empname, @empage, @empsalary"
```

Answer (score 0):

.CommandText = "spInsertDataIntoEmployee"
And try to send everything as nvarchar.

Comment: Sending everything as a `nvarchar`, even when it isn't, sounds like an awful idea.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the **most appropriate data type** - that's what they're there for, after all! Do ***NOT*** just send "everything as nvarchar" - **NOPE!**